# How to save an identity value of one table to foreign key of another table in entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables: `user` and `userprofile`

`User` has a column `id` which is an `identity` and is the primary key

`Userprofile` has the `userId` column which is a foreign key to `user.id`.

```
context.User.Add(userModel);
context.UserProfile.Add(userprofileMode);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But when I do `user.id = userprofile.Userid`, it doesn't save the value as it is identity column. How to save the value of id of user table to userid of userprofile table in Entity Framework?

Comment: Can you post your models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't - don't try and add a `User` and a `UserProfile` to the context and do the keys manually. You'd do something like:

```
User userModel = new userModel() {
  // Set properties
}

userModel.Profile = new UserProfile() {
  // Set properties
}

context.User.Add(userModel);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Entity Framework will sort out the keys automatically. Just simply add a UserProfile to the correct navigation property, add the user to your context, and save it.

Comment: Just for edification value, the reason it needs to be done this way is that the `User` won't actually have an id value until it is actually saved to the database, which doesn't happen until `SaveChanges` is called. You *could* add the `User`, save, then, set the foreign key for `UserProfile` and save again, but that just adds unnecessary work and overhead.