# mvc razor post to 2 models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have a Razor view that has form data. When I submit the form I want to enter one column(ID) in the "Form" model and also pass the entire form data to the "Init" model.

```
View: 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class =      "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Model 1 : Init

```
public partial class Init
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

Model 2 : Form

```
public partial class Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
    public int field3 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Init init)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Init.Add(init);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(init);
}
```

Comment: In a visual studiio, when you create a view ,choose the option of strongly type with model , to which you want the data.

Comment: The view I have is strongly typed to the Init model and on submit it adds data to the Init model. How do I also add the Id value from the form to another model(Form model) ?

Comment: What are `DocId`, `Supplier`, `SupplierText`? I do not see like properties not in model and not in view.

Comment: @adamshakhabov : My bad, I had changed the form field names for the sake of posting it here and I missed out on a few. I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Just create one input tag with an unique name for each of your models' items and let the model binder do its job.

In the example bellow the Id property is passed to modelA and modelB.

View Model

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Models

```
public class TestModelA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class TestModelB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModelA modelA, TestModelB modelB)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Receive")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10"> 

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="foo" class="control-label col-md-2">Foo</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" class="form-control text-box single-line" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bar" class="control-label col-md-2">Bar</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" class="form-control text-box single-line" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />

</div>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you want to save details into "Init" First. once it is saved pass the ID value of "Init" and save it into "Form" Model

First create the relationship between "Init" model and "Form" model

Add the following property in "Form" model

```
public int initID
```

I didn't test this one but I think it should help

```
        Init Initobj = new Init 
        {
            Id = Id ,
            DocId= DocId,
            SupplierText=SupplierText
            //other properties
        };
        db.Init.Add(Initobj);    
        db.SaveChanges();

        Form formobj = new Form
        {
            initID= Initobj.Id,

        };
        db.forms.Add(formobj);    
        db.SaveChanges();
```

You can check this link for reference
[Link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214345/how-to-save-an-identity-value-of-one-table-to-foreign-key-of-another-table-in-en)

Answer (score 0):

You should just continue:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id, name")] Init init,
                           [Bind(Include = "Id")] Form form)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Init.Add(init);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(init);
}
```